# How to use the same background color as a Paper component in Material-UI (dark mode + elevation)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

### Issue

I am trying to create a custom `Tab` component using the [styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/) method and I want my custom `Tab` to use the same background as a `Paper` with an elevation of 1.

I have an app that allows **light and dark mode**.

As you can see in the documentation (screenshot below), the **`Paper` component gets lighter and lighter when you increase the elevation**. This is done using the css property `background-image` (I inspected the html code to know that).

Usually, to make a custom component, I use the `theme` provided by MUI to access constants such as `background-color` of a `Paper`: `theme.palette.background.paper`. The problem is: I would like to have access to the constant for `background-image` (for elevation = 1).

I would like to have access to something like `theme.palette.backgroundImage.paper[1]`.

### Question

Is there any way to do that without hard-coding the values?

### Details

MUI version 5

[image: mui doc]